# How to impdp ? Oracle Multiple Dump File with their Corresponding Tables

Tags: oracle, shell, par, impdp

I am trying to import the data from dump file , so I created the test.par file which contains multiple dump file for each table and in the below table parameter I have mentioned the table name correspondingly.

**Test.Par**

```
 DUMPFILE=PIECE_HI.dmp,PIECE_HI_HIST.dmp
    DIRECTORY=ACSDB_DATAPUMP_DIR
    LOGFILE=impdp1.log
    table_exists_action=APPEND
    content=DATA_ONLY
    IGNORE=Y
    TABLES=PIECE_HI,PIECE_HI_HIST
```

While trying to access the par file from shell script, I am getting the below error

```
ORA-39001: invalid argument value
ORA-39000: bad dump file specification
ORA-39140: dump file "/appl/acs/loader/ACSDB_DATAPUMP_DIR/PIECE_STATUS.dmp" belongs to job "ACSAPPLUSR3"."SYS_EXPORT_TABLE_01"
```

Comment: If each file was exported separately, then they must be imported separately as well. DataPump does not support multiple unrelated dump files in the same job.

Comment: So to amplify @pmdba,  the export parameter file would have had to include something like `DUMPFILE=par_exp%u.dmp PARALLEL=4` and the import parameter file would have to have a matching parameter.  The `%u` provides a two-digit incrementing integer.

Comment: @MarkStewart That only applies if the original export was made from a single expdp job to multiple output files. It will not work to combine otherwise independent dump files produced by separate expdp jobs.

Comment: Right.  Seems like I tried to add more information for *future* efforts, and didn't word it clearly enough for current problem.